# How to make gridlines visible when cell background is black in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am using Microsoft Excel 2016. My objective is to have dark mode in Excel to make Excel more friendly to my eyes.

I changed the default cell background colour from white to black. I changed the default cell text from black to white. However, one problem that happened is that the gridlines have disappeared. I know I can change gridlines colour in File > Excel > Options. However, this changes the gridlines in all the worksheets in the Excel file. I only want to change gridline colour in a specific worksheet. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the the borders white

[image]

Select All Cells and click On borders button and select line color white, or the lightest shade of grey you can find which is near to white (some versions of Excel may not allow borders which are true white). Hope this helps.

Comment: Answer is almost correct except for the color white. When I choose color white, no borders can be added. DOn't know why. I had to choose a bright whitish color that is non-white. I am using Excel 2016. Would you mind modifying your answer to include my discovery about the white colour problem? Thank you. I have marked your answer as the right answer.